# Adding a swipe to next gesture using Syncfusion.SfChart

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Currently on my app when the user selects their 'symptom' they are directed to the detail page which shows their symptom chart with the populated feedback data from their selected symptom.

Is their a way i can add a swipe gesture to allow the user to swipe to the next symptom chart without having to go back to main symptoms page and selecting a symptom.

Currently this is how i populate my chart :

```
public async Task GetSymptomFeedback(string id)
    {

        SymptomFeedbackData.Clear();
        symptomChart.Series.Clear();



        BusyIndicator.IsRunning = true;
        SymptomFeedbackData = await symptomsfeedbackmanager.getUserSymptomFeedback(id);



        foreach (var FeedbackItem in SymptomFeedbackData)
        {

            FeedbackItem.Idusersymptomid =  FeedbackItem.Id + ',' + FeedbackItem.Usersymptomid;


        }

        IEnumerable<SymptomFeedback> OrdreredFeedbackData =  SymptomFeedbackData.OrderBy(X => X.DateTime);

        LineSeries columnseries = new LineSeries
        {
            ItemsSource = OrdreredFeedbackData,
            XBindingPath =  "DateTime",
            YBindingPath = "Intensity",

            DataMarker = new ChartDataMarker
            {
                ShowLabel = true,
                ShowMarker = true,
                MarkerHeight = 5,
                MarkerWidth = 5,
                MarkerColor = Xamarin.Forms.Color.Purple
            }

        };






        BusyIndicator.IsRunning = false;



        symptomChart.PrimaryAxis.ShowTrackballInfo = true;


        if (columnseries.ItemsSource != null)
        {
            symptomChart.Series.Add(columnseries);
        }


        symptomChart.ChartBehaviors.Add(new ChartTrackballBehavior());

        //Sort Collection by datetime 



        SymptomsList.ItemsSource = OrdreredFeedbackData.Reverse(); 


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

Through your code, we can see you query the data through the `id` of  symptom. So, I guess you pass this `id` as parameter when you go to the `detail page` from `main symptoms page`.

> Is their a way i can add a swipe gesture to allow the user to swipe to
>   the next symptom chart without having to go back to main symptoms page
>   and selecting a symptom.

In additional, you can pass a `array` of id of all symptoms to detail page. Let's name this array as `symptomIdArray`.

Then add a `SwipeGestureRecognizer` to your view.

```
    var DownSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Down };
    var UpSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Up };

    DownSwipeGesture.Swiped += OnSwiped;
    UpSwipeGesture.Swiped += OnSwiped;

    this.Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(DownSwipeGesture);
    this.Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(UpSwipeGesture);
```

In the `OnSwiped`, you can get `last` or `next` id through the `symptomIdArray` and `currentID` , and then you can choose to reload your current page or go to a new page to swipe to the next symptom chart, here is code:

```
  public Array symptomIdArray; // ids of all symptom

  public string currentID; // You selected id of current symptom

    void OnSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
            {

                int index = Array.IndexOf(symptomIdArray, currentID);

                switch (e.Direction)
                {
                    case SwipeDirection.Up:

                        if (index ==0)
                        {
                            //first one
                            break;
                        }

                        string lastID = (string)symptomIdArray.GetValue(index-1);

                        //1.You can refresh current page with lastId
                        GetSymptomFeedback(lastID);

                        //2.You can go to a new page with lastID ID and symptomIdArray
                        Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage(lastID, symptomIdArray));

                        break;

                    case SwipeDirection.Down:
                        // Handle the swipe

                        if (index ==  symptomIdArray.Length-1)
                        {
                            //Last one,  no more

                            break;
                        }

                        string nextID = (string)symptomIdArray.GetValue(index+1);

                        //1.You can refresh current page with next currentID
                        GetSymptomFeedback(nextID);


                        //2.You can go to a new page with nextID ID and symptomIdArray
                        Navigation.PushAsync(new NewPage(nextID, symptomIdArray));

                        break;
                }
            }
```

**Update:**

Add `SwipeGestureRecognizer`:

```
            SfChart chart = new SfChart();
            chart.Title.Text = "Chart";

            //Config chart....
            ...


            chart.Series.Add(series);
            this.Content = chart;

            var DownSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Down };
            var UpSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Up };

            DownSwipeGesture.Swiped += OnSwiped;
            UpSwipeGesture.Swiped += OnSwiped;

            chart.GestureRecognizers.Add(DownSwipeGesture);
            chart.GestureRecognizers.Add(UpSwipeGesture);
```

And `onSwipe`:

```
void OnSwiped(object sender, SwipedEventArgs e)
    {
            switch (e.Direction)
            {
                case SwipeDirection.Up:
                Console.WriteLine("up");
                    break;

                case SwipeDirection.Down:
                Console.WriteLine("down");

                break;
            }
    }
```

Let me know if you have any question.

Comment: Any time i try to add the swipe gesture to the chart it keeps giving me errors saying not recognised, any ideas how to do it ?

Comment: @MarkPW I don't use sfchart. Check these [threads](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/search?searchword=sfchart%20swipe%20gesture)  to see if they help. You can ask this question at their forum. Try [this](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/124277/unable-to-scroll-a-scrollviewer-when-swipe-gesture-starts-on-sfchart-control).

Comment: Is there a way i can just link it to the entire page so no matter were they swipe it will do it ? Any time i add the SwipeGestureRecognizer it just says 'the type SwipeGestureRecognizer  was not found.

Comment: @MarkPW How did you add SwipeGestureRecognizer? You should use `chart.GestureRecognizers.Add(DownSwipeGesture);`, I tested and it works for me. I will update my answer to show your the codes.